# Keyboard shortcut to add a worksheet to the right of the current sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, spreadsheet

Clicking on the <kbd>+</kbd> near the worksheets tab on Excel 2016 adds a new worksheet to the **right** of the current worksheet. However, hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> adds a worksheet to **left** of the current worksheet. The same happens when you use the ribbon to add a new worksheet (<kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>I</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>).

How do I make Excel to add a worksheet to the right of the current sheet while using a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a VBA macro.  This macro will add a new worksheet to the right of the active sheet:

```vb
Sub SheetAdder()
    Dim w As Worksheet
    Set w = ActiveSheet
    Sheets.Add after:=w
End Sub
```

Once installed, you can assign a shortcut key to it like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I haven't found a way to do that for a single sheet. But if you want to add **2 sheets** to the right of the current sheet then just

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd>, then
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>

No need for a VBA script. This also works for more than 2 sheets but the new sheets will be put on the left of the last sheet, because basically it's still <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> which adds a new sheet to the last selected sheet